# How to check if file is already in the cache?

Tags: python

i am working on a Tool which can post Ingame News Updates from Games on your Twitter Account, in the last few Days I searched for an solution to find a way to look if an image is already in the cache so it wont be posted again if a News Feed Update of an Game is online, it should only post the new ones and skip the old ones (actually it posts every active News Feed again), the problem is can't do it. I tested it about 100 Times but it wont work. I really hope that one of you can help me with this issue because it would be fantastic if this Tool would work with an method like this. Thanks for every single help in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
import time
from colorama import *
init()

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('API', 'APISECRET')
auth.set_access_token('ACESS', 'ACESSSECRET')

response = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/news/br')
newsData = response.json()["data"]


#-----
footer = '#Fortnite'
delay = 5
saveImages = True
#-----

while 1:
    response = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/news/br')
    if response:
        newsDataLoop = response.json()["data"]
        print("2 - Checking for change in news feed...")

        if newsData != newsDataLoop:
        #if loop == True:
            print("News Feed has changed...")
            for i in newsDataLoop["motds"]:
                try:
                    print("Saving: "+i["id"])
                    url = i["image"]
                    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
                    open("NewsImages/"+i["id"]+'.png', 'wb').write(r.content)
                    print("Saved: "+i["id"])
                    try:
                        api = tweepy.API(auth)
                        api.update_with_media("NewsImages/"+i["id"]+'.png',"Fortnite News Update:\n\n"+i["title"]+":\n"+i["body"]+"\n\n"+footer)
                        print("Tweeted: "+i["id"])
                    except:
                        print("Failed to tweet: "+i["id"])
                    if saveImages == 'False':
                        os.remove("NewsImages/"+i["id"]+'.png')

                    response = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/news/br')
                    newsData = response.json()["data"]
                except:
                    print("Error in tweeting news feed: skipping")
            print("Finished news feed publishing")
    else:
        print("FAILED TO GRAB NEWS DATA: URL DOWN")

    time.sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each `motd` to see if it existed in the old dataset.

```py
import tweepy
import time
from colorama import *
init()

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('API', 'APISECRET')
auth.set_access_token('ACESS', 'ACESSSECRET')

response = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/news/br')
newsData = response.json()["data"]


#-----
footer = '#Fortnite'
delay = 5
saveImages = True
#-----

while 1:
    response = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/news/br')
    if response:
        newsDataLoop = response.json()["data"]
        print("2 - Checking for change in news feed...")

        if newsData != newsDataLoop:
        #if loop == True:
            print("News Feed has changed...")
            for i in newsDataLoop["motds"]:
                if i in newsData["motds"]:
                    # has already been posted
                    print("Already posted")
                    continue
                try:
                    print("Saving: "+i["id"])
                    url = i["image"]
                    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
                    open("NewsImages/"+i["id"]+'.png', 'wb').write(r.content)
                    print("Saved: "+i["id"])
                    try:
                        api = tweepy.API(auth)
                        api.update_with_media("NewsImages/"+i["id"]+'.png',"Fortnite News Update:\n\n"+i["title"]+":\n"+i["body"]+"\n\n"+footer)
                        print("Tweeted: "+i["id"])
                    except:
                        print("Failed to tweet: "+i["id"])
                    if saveImages == 'False':
                        os.remove("NewsImages/"+i["id"]+'.png')

                    response = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/news/br')
                    newsData = response.json()["data"]
                except:
                    print("Error in tweeting news feed: skipping")
            print("Finished news feed publishing")
    else:
        print("FAILED TO GRAB NEWS DATA: URL DOWN")

    time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Can I somehow make it so that the Bot print then something like "Already posted"?

Comment: yep, just add a print statement after my comment `#has already been posted`.